# Present tense to express present or future action

Tags: meaning, verbs, tenses

In the following sentence, "ti lascio" is conjugated at the indicativo presente :

> Caso mai tu volessi chiamarmi, ti lascio il mio numero.

Should we understand

> In case you want to call me, I let you my phone number. (now)

or

> In case you want to call me, I will let you my phone number. (later, if you ask for it)

... ?

Does indicativo presente often has the value of a future tense, as would be expressed by a future tense in other languages ?

Comment: Many native speakers in informal speech use *indicativo presente* to refer to future actions - it's usually clear from the context. I can't remember the last time someone told me "domani andrò al cinema" - people usually say "domani vado al cinema". This use is also present in some English conditionals - e.g., "If **it rains** tomorrow, I won't cycle to work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence quoted (*Caso mai tu volessi chiamarmi, ti lascio il mio numero*) can only be understood as Person #1 (the speaker) giving Person #2 (the listener) their phone number now, in case #2 wants, in some future time, to call #1. If the other sense were meant, one could say:

> Caso mai tu volessi chiamarmi, ti darò il mio numero.

or something like it (but it would be a little strange: we should contrive a situation where #2 can contact #1, but not by phone, to get their number).

As to the last question, perhaps it deserves a separate question. The short answer is that indeed, in some cases, especially in informal speech, one uses present to mean future; for instance: *Se domani piove, non facciamo la gita*.

Comment: in #2 the two persons could be at the beginning of the discussion...